# Android - downloading an image to byte[] and displaying it as Drawable in ImageView

Tags: android, image, download, android-asynctask, byte

I am trying to download an image from a URL to a byte[] and then display it as a drawable in an imageView. I use AsyncTask to download the method and then use onPostExecute() to display it but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't get any errors.

[FIXED]

Answer (score 3):

try to display the image in a WebView like this

```
  byte[] imageRaw = yourImage;
  String image64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageRaw, Base64.DEFAULT);
  String pageData = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + image64 + "\" />";
```

Comment: I need to use an image view

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps, but in a similar app I created a `Bitmap` also using the `BitmapFactory` and updated an `ImageView` using `setImageBitmap` followed by `refreshDrawableState`.